# JQuery DatePicker not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jQuery [DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default) in my website. I want the two dropdown on datepicker : one is for selecting month and one is for selecting year. Therefore i should write in the below format:

```
     $('.datepicker').datepicker({ 
     changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
```

I want to make this picker reusable therefore i make a function which takes the format parameters like given below:

```
    function RegisterDateTimePicker(options) {

var test = "{" + options + "}";

$('.date').datepicker(test);
}
```

The parameter "options" above is a variable which consist of string

```
    "changeMonth: true, changeYear: true"
```

Now datepicker is not showing. The error i get while debugging is:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
```

kindly provide the way to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

options should be an object, not a string. you are doing it wrong!

if `options` were an object, you could change the function to this (to make it work):

```
function RegisterDateTimePicker(options) {
  $('.date').datepicker(options);
}
```

but its not an object, its a string, which is a bad idea. you should change it to an object unless you have a **really** good reason to keep it as string - which you should explain to me before i can help you any further.

**edit**:
instead of passing in a string you should pass in an object maybe like this:

```
var options = { 
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
};
//now call your function:
RegisterDateTimePicker(options);
```

or maybe you want to have your resuable function always make the datepicker with the same options? then do this:

```
function RegisterDateTimePicker(options) {
  var options = { 
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
  };
  $('.date').datepicker(options);
}
```

Comment: oh..which type of object? And how can i change this string to that type of object?

Comment: you cant easily change the string to an object without parsing it. why is it a string in the first place? you should just construct an object and pass that! ill include an example in the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in such a manner:

```
var options ={changeMonth: true, changeYear: true};
RegisterDateTimePicker(options);
```